# DosBox - special letters and Caps Lock

Tags: ms-dos, localization, dosbox

There's one problem I have with all major builds of Dosbox (Daum and Megabuild). With Caps lock enabled, I get capital letters from English alphabet, but in order to write capitals in German, French, Czech, Polish etc. I need to hold Shift as well.

Does anyone know a fix for that? I'm on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it means that you have to change the code page to that of the country of the language you wish to use. See the following for more information:

http://www.computerhope.com/chcphlp.htm

The down side is that you will lose access to many of the block graphics that you find in the default code page which is code page 437 (Latin US). If being able to write text in several languages is more important to you than using the block graphics then I would suggest using code page 850 (Multilingual).

Hope this helps.